# Rewrite all subdomain URLs with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a domain `test.com` and a subdomain `sub.test.com`.

Now, I need to rewrite the URL `sub.test.com` to `test.com/?state=sub`, and the URLs like  `sub.test.com/content/` to `test.com/content/?state=sub`, and `sub.test.com/content/proceed/` to `test.com/content/proceed/?state=sub`.

The rule for the first URL worked, something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webmail\.test\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.test\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.test\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots.txt.*
RewriteRule  ^$ http://www.test.com/?state=%1 [P]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www|webmail|m)\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.test.com%{REQUEST_URI}/?state=%1 [P]
```